# Why is my code O(N^2) if there is only one for loop

Tags: python, performance, time, counting

I am trying to solve problem 4.1 on Codility.com. I need a solution which runs in O(N) time. My code solves the problem, but it runs in O(N^2) time, according to Codility's performance tests. Unfortunately I can't see why. There is only one for loop, which should scale linearly with n.

The challenge is to write a solution which tests whether an array ('A') contains all integers between 1 and X. It should return the index of the element which is the last element in 1 to X that appears in the array, or it should return -1 if not every integer between 1 and X is an element of the array. For example, the solution to X = 4 and A = [1, 3, 4, 2, 2] is 3 since 2 is the last element in 1 to 4 which appears in the array and it first appears in position 3. The solution to X = 5 and A = [1, 2, 4, 2, 3] is -1 because 5 never appears. My solution is below.

```
def Solution(X, A):
N = len(A)
count = [0] * (X + 1)

# Solution for single-element arrays
if N == 1: 
    
    if A[0] == 1:
        return 0
    elif A[0] != 1:
        return - 1

# Solution for multi-element arrays
elif N != 1:
    
    for i in range(0, N + 1, 1):
        if count[A[i]] == 0:
            count[A[i]] = count[A[i]] + 1
        else:
            pass
        if count == [0] + [1] * (X):
            return i 
        elif count != [0] + [1] * (X) and i == N - 1: 
            return -1
```

Would anyone know why it runs in O(N^2) time? Codility's performance tests confirm this, but as far as I can see this should run in O(kN) time since there is only one for loop. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This line: `count == [0] + [1] * (X)` Looks like an O(N) operation. It will need to create a list with X elements, which takes time that scales linearly with X.

Comment: Looks like the loop as a whole is `O(NX)`.  Not sure what inputs it runs on in Codility, but if typical inputs have X roughly proportional to N, then the measured behaviour will be roughly `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work in O(n), you would have to adjust it to the exact question given:

```py
def solution(x, a):
    
    b = []
    for v in a:
        # the conditions
        if (type(v) == int) and (v < x) and (v>1): b.append(v)
        else: return -1
            
    return b

# some examples

# this returns -1
a = [1,2,3,4,5.5,6]
x = solution(5,a)
print(x)


# this returns the the list [2, 3, 4]
a = [2,3,4]
x = solution(5,a)
print(x)
```

the reason why is because you can exit the list at the first fail with the `return -1` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should be O(N): a single instantiation of a list of length `X`, one for-loop over `A` which does O(1) retrieval of single list items, and one single final search of the list for `None` values.

```
def solution(X, A):
    pos = [None] * X
    for i, n in enumerate(A):
        if 1 <= n <= X:
            if pos[n-1] is None:
                pos[n-1] = i
    return pos[n-1] if None not in pos else -1

print(solution(4, [1, 3, 4, 2, 2]))
print(solution(5, [1, 2, 4, 2, 3]))
print(solution(1000, reversed(range(1, 1001))))
```

prints:

```
3
-1
999
```